# Javascript: How can I get the attribute data of a button's parent ID?

Tags: javascript, html

As the title says, I'm trying to get the attribute value of a button's containing (parent) element, called `data-id'.

Current code is this:

```
 function onClickGetId(e) {
    //grab data-id number from HTML
    var dataId = document.getElementById("data-id"); <-- returns null right now, need to pull from HTML
    var dataIdFromRow = dataId.getAttribute("data-id");
    var textForVCs = '';
    for (i = 0; i < currentVCData.length; i++) {
        if (currentVCData[i][0] == dataIdFromRow) {
            textForVCs = textForVCs + " " + currentVCData[i][1];

            }
    }
    return textForVCs;
    }
```

What should I add in order to make it grab the attribute from the parent ID?

Comment: Could you show structure of HTML? Maybe something wrong in there.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Somehting wrong in HTML and then you use document.getElementById("data-id"); get wrong or null result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution! It turns out that I needed to refer to an attribute of a parent of a parent node, using the syntax `var dataId = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-id");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

First get the element ID

```
var testVar = document.getElementById("divID");
```

Then use that first variable where you got the element ID to get the data attribute you need.

```
var show = testVar.getAttribute("data-id");
```

Check out this codePen.. let me know if that's what you're looking for. It's working for me. https://codepen.io/tetonhiker/pen/WjZrbo

Comment: I already have that in my code, but I still get a null value.

Comment: is the elementID really called data-id? Or is that the actual data attribute you're trying to call

Answer (score 0):

The Parent from an Element is "parentNode"

Try this.parentNode.dataset.id

or

e.parentNode.dataset.id

or make a smal fiddle with yor js and html..

Answer (score 0):

Here the code HTML:

```
<div data-id="test">
  <button onclick="action(this)">
    CLICK ME
  </button>
</div>
```

Here the JS:

```
function action(element) {
    console.log(element.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id'));
}
```

The working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/0tqsepap/2/